# What is meaning of Folder tag in csproj

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, visual-studio-2022, csproj

in .NET C# project, with `csproj` file that follow `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` template, I have some item group like below

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Internal\" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I try to understand what is meaning of this tag with [official documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props). But I do not find anything.

So, my question is, **What is this tag (What is meaning of that?)? and When I add my directory in csproj as `Folder` tag?**

I try the search query in https://stackoverflow.com/a/71049728/1539100 but i do not find any useful result in Bing

thanks

Comment: I shared where it comes from and why you can't find the document. You can see my answer.  :)

Comment: Hi sorosh, any update of this? :)

Comment: Why? Because git doesn't store empty folders. So a .csproj needs a way to track that an empty folder should exist, even if it isn't there on disk.

Answer (score 3):

This simply means, You have created a subfolder in your project.
Look in the Solution Explorer - You should see a folder with the same name.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the virtual structure of your project and does not mirror the structure on disk. Usually, it is used for structuring solutions in VS.

Answer (score 0):

From the description of your question, I think you want the official document to clarify this, right?

If so, The MSBuild documentation does not write this thing at all. Maybe Microsoft thinks this element can be understood literally, so it has not explained it, but you can see the role of this Element elsewhere:

[Folder element (Visual Studio project templates) in VS Tools Extensionbility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/?view=vs-2022)

As it mentioned, Specifies a folder that will be added to the project.

The actual effect is add folder and it's contents to VS project UI:

[image]

---

By the way, this element comes from [Microsoft.Build.Commontypes.xsd](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/blob/master/Source/MSBuild.Community.Tasks/Microsoft.Build.Commontypes.xsd#L161).

The confusion you're experiencing with not being able to find documentation is entirely due to missing documentation, which should appear here:

[Common MSBuild project items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2022)

Folder element should indeed be stated in the above document, you can understand this from the xsd definition.

You can feedback the document lack here:

[image]